# Angular + meteor : observable is realy long

Tags: angular, meteor, observable

i'm currently try to use a module in meteor with angular 4.

I want to take all data with a specific newsfeed and use this data in my application.

When i subscribe the data, it takes between 1-2 minutes to make the research and give an array.

this is my code :

in the client folder :
newsfeed-planning.component.ts

```
getTask() {
    this.subTaskPublish =
    MeteorObservable.subscribe('TaskList')
                    .subscribe(() => {
        this.tasks = TaskCollection.find({newsfeed : this.newsfeedID}, {fields : {_id : 0, newsfeed: 0}}).fetch();
        console.log(this.tasks);
    });
}
```

and in the server folder :
task.ts

```
Meteor.publish('TaskList', function() {
    return TaskCollection.find({});
})
```

if you need more informations i can give you what you need.

task.model.ts :

```
export class TaskCollectionModel {
id: number;
start_date: string;
text: string;
progress: number;
duration: number;
parent: number;
newsfeed: string;
}
```

Comment: Using Pagination/ Infinite Scroll may be a solution for you

Comment: Yep, use the `limit` modifier in the mongo query to show only few results initially. There are good tuts on the above mentioned methods. Works very well with meteor.